# JAGS in R: Resulting MCMC chain does not start near initial values

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, jags, rjags

I am running the code in [this](https://www.rensvandeschoot.com/tutorials/rjags-how-to-get-started/) simple Rjags tutorial. Notice that the initial values of the parameters are specified by `model.inits <- list(tau=1, beta0=1, beta1=0, beta2=0)`. I wanted to test that the resulting MCMC chain actually starts at those initial values.

Therefore, for testing purposes, within `jags.model()`, I set `n.adapt=0`, so no adaptation takes place. Printing `head(model.samples[[1]])` results in the first row having `beta0` at 0.58, `beta1` at 0.97, and `beta2` at 0.54. Thus, after just the first iteration, none of the parameters are even close to their initializations.

Would appreciate an explanation as to whether I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that JAGS doesn't record the initial values as the first of the sampled values.  Using your example, I put the model in a file called `regression.mod`, the data in a file called `regression.dat` and the initial values in a file called `regression.inits`.  Then, I opened up the terminal and started JAGS (rather than running through R, though it should work the same in R).  I did the following:

```
(base) david@Daves-MacBook-Pro Downloads % jags              
Welcome to JAGS 4.3.1 (official binary) on Fri Mar 31 07:27:34 2023
JAGS is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Loading module: basemod: ok
Loading module: bugs: ok
. model in regression.mod

. data in regression.dat
Reading data file regression.dat

. compile
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
Graph information:
   Observed stochastic nodes: 500
   Unobserved stochastic nodes: 4
   Total graph size: 3023

. parameters in regression.inits
Reading parameter file regression.inits

. initialize   
Initializing model

. parameters to actual.txt, chain(1)
```

The results of `parameters to` shows the current state of the initialized model.  That confirms the initial values are set appropriately.

```
`.RNG.name` <- "base::Wichmann-Hill"
`.RNG.state` <- 
c(16850L,14297L,4084L)
`beta0` <- 
1
`beta1` <- 
0
`beta2` <- 
0
`tau` <- 
1
```

Next, I took one draw from the posterior and saved the values for that one draw:

```
. monitor tau      
. monitor beta1
. monitor beta2
. monitor beta0
. update 1
Updating 1

. coda *, stem(samp1_)
```

The results show that the information from the single draw was:

```
tau    0.336252
beta1  0.896834
beta2  0.583655
beta0  0.393297
```

The other big sign is that if you set monitors directly after initialization and save the values for the chains, the files are empty, meaning that JAGS doesn't put the initial values in with the sampled values.

---

##### Edit: Answer questions in comments

The question in the comment is - shouldn't the chain move more slowly from the initial values?  The answer is - it depends.  In particular, it depends on the correlation structure of the X variables (and by extension, the correlation structure of the parameters, and whether that correlation structure is built into the model).  Below is a simple two independent variable regression problem (without intercept).  In one model, the x variables are uncorrelated in the other, they correlate at 0.93 (in the population).  The priors on the regression coefficients are independent normals.  I started the b values (at -25, 25) way away from their actual values (-1,1).  The figure at the bottom shows that when the x-variables are uncorrelated, the sampler moves almost immediately to the stationary distribution.  When the x-variables are highly correlated, it takes much longer to get there.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(rjags)
library(coda)
set.seed(519)
mod <- "model{
  for(i in 1:250){
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
    mu[i] <- inprod(X[i,], b)
  }
  tau ~ dgamma(1,.1)
  b[1] ~ dnorm(0,.01)
  b[2] ~ dnorm(0,.01)
}"

uncor_X <- MASS::mvrnorm(250, c(0,0), diag(2))

b <- c(-1, 1)

y1 <- uncor_X %*%b + rnorm(250, 0, 1)

cor_X <- MASS::mvrnorm(250, c(0,0), matrix(c(1, .93, .93, 1), ncol=2))
y2 <- cor_X %*% b + rnorm(250, 0, .25)


inits <- list(b=c(-25, 25), tau=1)

library(rjags)
mod_u <- jags.model(textConnection(mod), 
                    data = list(X = uncor_X, y=c(y1)), 
                    inits = inits, 
                    n.adapt=0)
#> Compiling model graph
#>    Resolving undeclared variables
#>    Allocating nodes
#> Graph information:
#>    Observed stochastic nodes: 250
#>    Unobserved stochastic nodes: 3
#>    Total graph size: 1258
#> 
#> Initializing model
samp_u <- coda.samples(mod_u, variable.names = c("b", "tau"), n.iter=100)

mod_c <- jags.model(textConnection(mod), 
                    data = list(X = cor_X, y=c(y2)), 
                    inits = inits, 
                    n.adapt=0)
#> Compiling model graph
#>    Resolving undeclared variables
#>    Allocating nodes
#> Graph information:
#>    Observed stochastic nodes: 250
#>    Unobserved stochastic nodes: 3
#>    Total graph size: 1258
#> 
#> Initializing model
samp_c <- coda.samples(mod_c, variable.names = c("b", "tau"), n.iter=100)

sampc <- tibble::as_tibble(samp_c[[1]]) %>% 
  rbind(c(-25, 25, 1), .) %>% 
  setNames(c("b1", "b2", "tau")) %>% 
  mutate(structure = "Correlated")
sampu <- tibble::as_tibble(samp_u[[1]]) %>% 
  rbind(c(-25, 25, 1), .) %>% 
  setNames(c("b1", "b2", "tau")) %>% 
  mutate(structure = "Uncorrelated")

samps <- bind_rows(sampu, sampc)
ggplot(samps, aes(x=b1, y=b2)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=.1) + 
  geom_path(alpha=.1) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=-23, y=25,label="Start"), inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(~structure, ncol=2)
```

[image]

However, even with correlated data, if we use a bivariate normal prior distribution for the coefficients that can accommodate correlated parameters, the slow mixing goes away

```r
mnmod <- "model{
  for(i in 1:250){
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
    mu[i] <- inprod(X[i,], b)
  }
  tau ~ dgamma(1,.1)
  b ~ dmnorm(b0, B0)
}"

mod_mn <- jags.model(textConnection(mnmod), 
                    data = list(X = cor_X, y=c(y2), b0=c(0,0), B0 = diag(2)*.01), 
                    inits = inits, 
                    n.adapt=0)
#> Compiling model graph
#>    Resolving undeclared variables
#>    Allocating nodes
#> Graph information:
#>    Observed stochastic nodes: 250
#>    Unobserved stochastic nodes: 2
#>    Total graph size: 1262
#> 
#> Initializing model
samp_mn <- coda.samples(mod_mn, variable.names = c("b", "tau"), n.iter=100)

sampmn <- tibble::as_tibble(rbind(c(-25, 25, 1), samp_mn[[1]])) %>% setNames(c("b1", "b2", "tau"))


ggplot(sampmn, aes(x=b1, y=b2)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=.1) + 
  geom_path(alpha=.1) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=-23, y=25,label="Start"), inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi @DaveArmstrong, thanks for your thorough answer! Quick follow-up, though - if the initial values aren't put with the sampled values, shouldn't the first few samples still be very close to the initial values? Usually when you look at the plot of the chain, it moves slowly from around the initial values towards the target values. But not seeing that here - I'm seeing it pretty close to the target values from the beginning.

Comment: @bob I added an explanation to the bottom of my answer - the short answer is it depends on the correlation of model parameters and whether that correlation is anticipated by the model.

Comment: Appreciate the thoroughness @DaveArmstrong!

Comment: if we were to not specify `n.adapt` (thus letting it default to 1000), would the `inits` get ignored (though specified)?

Comment: @bob, no the inits should still be where the chain starts, it is just that the `n.adapt` iterations are used to tune the parameters of the sampler.